# Set value in RatingBar

Tags: android

I can't set rating for the RatingBar. My code below. How can I set a default rating for dynamically added RatingBar?
Here is my code.

```
public class DialogRate extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener {
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    LinearLayout ll_dialog = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_dialog);     
    final RatingBar rate_bar = new RatingBar(context);
    rate_bar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
    rate_bar.setStepSize((float) 0.5);
    rate_bar.setMax(5);
    rate_bar.setId(1);   
    rate_bar.setRating(2.0f); // Error occur on this line!
    ll_dialog.addView(rate_bar);
}
...
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     TextView rate_val = (TextView) findViewById(0);
     rate_val.setText(Float.toString(ratingBar.getRating()));
}
```

Error Stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1645    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1663 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 931   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

**Close**

Sorry guys this error is simple. The TextView in onRatingChanged dynamically created after setRating.

Comment: a) Always add the error. b) maybe you have to `setNumStars()`

Comment: Error - Source not found. setNumStars() not helps me :(

Comment: It would be `rate_bar.setNumStars(5);`. Please add the full error message you get from logcat to your post. Without you don't get more than speculations.

Comment: This error I get in LogCat: GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 103K, 51% free 2681K/5447K, external 2121K/2137K, paused 76ms.

Comment: Thats not related to your code. The error looks somehow like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750863/baseexpandablelistadapter-runtimeerror-nullpointerexception (LogCat)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
rate_bar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("2.0"));
```

or use this:

```
rate_bar.setRating(0.0f);
```

Comment: Why would you want to specify that as a `String`, then parse it so it becomes a `float`? `rate_bar.setRating(2f);` does the same (and even if you don't explicitly declare it float it would work because Java will automatically convert is to float.)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but for Kotlin this how you can achieve the same

```
`val rate=2
 rate_bar.rating = rate.toFloat()`
```