# BaseExpandableListAdapter RuntimeError NullPointerException

Tags: android, arraylist, expandablelistview

I'm trying to view data from a database in an ExpandableListView (I'm first trying to get it working with hard coded Strings).

I've used the following example: [CodeWiki ExpandableListView](http://en.wikicode.org/index.php/Custom_ExpandableListView#Results)

But I get a Runtime error when I click on a group to get the childView.

Categories1.java

```
public class CategoriesActivity1 extends Activity
```

{

```
ExpandableListView eListView;
ExpandableListAdapter eListAdapter;

ArrayList<String> groups;
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> children;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories);

        eListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

        loadData();

        MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this, groups, children);

        eListView.setAdapter(adapter);


 }



 private void loadData(){

        groups= new ArrayList<String>();
        children= new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();

        groups.add("Group 1");
        groups.add("Group 2");
        groups.add("Group 3");

        children.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
        children.get(0).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(0).get(0).add("Child 1 group 1");
        children.get(0).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(0).get(1).add("Child 2 group 1");
        children.get(0).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(0).get(2).add("Child 3 group 1");

        children.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
        children.get(1).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(1).get(0).add("Child 1 group 2");
        children.get(1).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(1).get(1).add("Child 2 group 2");
        children.get(1).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(1).get(2).add("Child 3 group 2");

        children.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
        children.get(2).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(2).get(0).add("Child 1 group 3");
        children.get(2).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(2).get(1).add("Child 2 group 3");
        children.get(2).add(new ArrayList<String>());
        children.get(2).get(2).add("Child 3 group 3");
    }
```

}

MyExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
```

{

```
private ArrayList<String> groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> children;
    private Context context;

public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> children)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children = children;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    String child = (String) ((ArrayList<String>)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(0);

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_group, null);
    }

    TextView childTxt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewChild01);

    childTxt.setText(child);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return children.get(groupPosition).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount()
{
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    String group = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_group, null);
    }

    TextView groupTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewGroup);

    groupTxt.setText(group);


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return true;
}
```

}

categories_group.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/categoriesLLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewGroup" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewChild01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

> 03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at nl.test.listing.activity.MyExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(MyExpandableListAdapter.java:64)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:450)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   03-17 15:16:13.468: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I don't know why I get this error, looking at the example I only changed the xml values from px to dp.

Comment: what is MyExpandableListAdapter.java, line 64? Probably `getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(0);` and that would mean that your list is either not initialized yet or there is something wrong with that list in a list in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is at class "MyExpandableListAdapter" at line number 64. Here it seems that there is some variable is becoming null at that moment. Can you paste the code at line number 64 in this class. SO that i can assist you more.

Comment: childTxt.setText(child); is the code on line 64 but he gets the child variable from a few lines above that in the getChildView() method

Comment: I think the childTxt is becoming null. Check whether the TextViewChild01 object is present in the layout categories_group.

Comment: In the example there's only 1 TextView in categories_group and the TextViewChild01 is in categories_child, but when I put TextViewChild01 on the categories_group.xml it works!! Thanks